# Were Kohanim forbidden from serving in King David's army?

Tags: army-military-war, divorce, king-david

The gemara in a couple places ([Shabbos 56a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.56a.8-10?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en), [Kesuvos 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.9b.1?lang=bi)) tells us that before leaving to battle, the soldiers in King David's army would give a conditional *get* to their wives in order to prevent a situation where if a soldier did not return from battle and there were no witnesses to his fate, the wife wouldn't be an *agunah* and would be able to remarry.

Now if a Levi or Yisrael was presumed missing but then found, they could easily remarry their wife. However, a Kohein would be unable to remarry his wife since he is prohibited from marrying a divorcée.

**In light of this, were Kohanim forbidden from serving in King David's army?**

Comment: Benayahu ben Yehoyada was one of David's main warriors. I don't know if he was an exception.

Comment: If the *get* was conditional, then would they even have to remarry their wives? Once the Kohen finally turns up, the *get* should be annulled retroactively. Unless the condition was that they didn’t return within X days of the war ending, in which case that’s not reason to prohibit them, but rather a risk that the Kohanim would be required to take.

Comment: @DonielF right- majority of the time would hopefully be ok, but the edge cases (ex: set amount of time expires and then husband appears, miraculously appears, is held hostage -> conditional *get* is granted -> is freed) would be a problem

Comment: Masuach milchama...

Comment: Wouldn't Kohenim be constantly exposing themselves to the risk of contamination by corpse tumeh just by virtue of being on the battlefield? Are they not forbidden from doing just that?

Comment: @JoshK also a good question. Can suggest that war is *docheh* the *issur* of *tumah* and even then they still could become *tahor* via the Parah Adumah. However a Kohein divorcing his wife is permanent with no fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the subject of an old debate when it comes to kohanim giving conditional divorces. [R. Mordechai Ben Hillel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_ben_Hillel) wrote that one cannot bring a proof from the fact that kohanim at war gave such conditional divorces, because it is possible that there were no kohanim there (as even the *mashuach milchama* could have left after making the announcements), and according to some interpretations the divorces of those going to war were *not* conditional, but full-fledged divorces.

**Mordechai Gittin # 432**

> אמנם אין להביא ראיה מכל היוצא למלחמת בית דוד כו' דהא גם כהנים היו עמהם ולכל הפחות צריך להיות עמהם כהן אחד הקורא מי האיש הירא ורך הלבב דא"כ מה שאל התלמוד פ"ק דקדושין כהן מהו ביפת תואר תיפוק ליה דכהן היה במלחמה דגם כהן משוח היה במלחמה אלא ודאי לא קאי עליה דשמא היה חוזר לביתו ולא היה נכנס בעורכי המלחמה גם בנדון זה לא תפשוט ועוד דיש מפרשים דההיא דכל היוצא למלחמת בית דוד כו' שהיו נותנין גט גמור מעכשיו כדפי' בפ"ק דכתובות ובשבת בפרק במה בהמה ע"כ

However, [R. Binyamin Ze'ev Ben Matityahu](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%96%D7%90%D7%91_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%94) did bring precisely this proof from the fact that there must have been kohanim at the war:

**[Shu"t Binyamin Ze'ev # 102](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=621&pgnum=336)**

> תדע דגבי מלחמת בית דוד אמרינן בשבת פ' במה בהמ' ומייתי לה נמי פ"ק דכתובות דכל היוצא במלחמת בית דוד גט כריתות כותב לאשתו פירוש ע"ת שאם ימות במלחמה תהא מגורשת והתם ע"כ צ"ל דהיה שם כהן דהא כהן משוח מלחמה היה עמהם שקורא אליהם בלשון הקדש שמע ישראל אתם קרבים היום למלחמה וכהן מדב' ושוטר משמיע כדאיתא בסוטה פרק משוח מלחמה ואי אפשר לומר דאחר שהיה קורא הכהן הפסוק לישראל היה חוזר לביתו ולא היה נכנס לעורכי מלחמה דהא הארון יוצא עמהם במלחמה כדכתיב כי ה' אלהיכם ההולך עמכם ופירש"י בפרשת שופטים ההולך עמכם זה מחנה הארון וה' וכל כינוייו עומדים בארון כדפירש"י בסוטה פרק משוח מלחמה והארון הכהנים היו נושאין אותו ובודאי כשהיה חוזר ההוא כהן היה מחזיר את אשתו ומקיימה ואי איתא דחיישינן מתנאו איך היה מחזירה ההוא כהן הא גרושה היתה אם היה מת במלחמה אלא ע"כ צ"ל מדהיה מחזירה הו' וכל א' מישראל דהא בא בתוך הזמן ולא נגמר התנאי בטל הגט מאליו וחוזר ומקיימה ולא פסלה מן הכהונה

Comment: Interesting that they don't mention Benyahau as I did

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw someone ask that as a question on the Mordechai.